# What type of page should i use? static page or category page? and what's the difference?

Tags: categories, pages, archives

I’m a new WordPress user and i’m very confused about my how the structure of my website should be.

I’m creating a language learning website and i started with the static pages (Home, about, etc.)

Then i wanted to create the pages related to the specific languages (Englsh, Spanish for example) and for that, i created more static pages which would have a organized list of the lessons that of course have an specific order, lesson 1, 2, 3, and so on.
the URLS would be something like: website.com/french

I wanted to make sure i was doing things right so i searched my website on Google and i saw pages called ‘French lessons archives’ with these URL: website.com/category/french that seem to be the category pages.

My questios are:
– What should i do? should i use the static pages i created? or the category page?
– Should i delete or nonindex the category page?

As a reminder, my content has an specific order, they are lessons so i don’t want the order to be updated everytime i create a lesson.

- I read something online saying category pages are important for SEO but i don’t know what to do and i have not found an asnwer in this forums yet, i hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question, and welcome to the world of Wordpress. Many people here may say this isn't the right question for this site, but I think it's a great one!

There's really no perfect way to *do* Wordpress, and almost always there are a lot of options to do it *right* or *well*.

Categories can be important for SEO and they can be a great tool, but don't get hung up about this. As long as you have good content, and real humans can navigate your site, you should be satisfying the basics of SEO in terms of your site's structure.

The question of 'how' you should do this really comes down to your personal choice, and also that of the theme or template you're working with (or building if you're here to build things yourself!)

Perhaps make sure you're testing how things change when you add content and new pages. From the information you've given, I'd probably suggest you do these as **child pages** rather than categories, since child pages will give you better control over your 'flow' and 'page order' whereas categories will normally order themselves alphabetically.

See how you go and I hope things work out for you!